# language for creating contract template

Tags: javascript, template-engine

I Want to create an application for contracts (example : employment contrat) templates generating.
Something like a template engine. 
I want to develop this app with Javascript.
I'm not a good code writer (i'm in BI field), and i want to know if it's a good idea to use Javascript ? Is there another language that fits better my need ?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is probably going to get locked due to it being too broad, but if you are in BI you might want to consider something like Microsoft Lightswitch (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2011/12/01/beginning-lightswitch-getting-started.aspx). It makes it pretty easy to build form centered interfaces which sounds like what you are trying to do.